# What is the best way to introduce tensor products to undergrads?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, soft-question, tensor-products, mathematics-education

What is the best way to introduce vector space tensor products to undergrads? We have a number of options, given in no particular order.

1. The universal property proving uniqueness and not existence.
2. The universal property proving uniqueness and existence.
3. A concrete basis construction.

Clearly it is best to follow 2) but the existence tends to lose people, so maybe 1) is best? 3) is of course very easy to get across, but has obvious problems from a rigour point of view. Do people have opinions?

Comment: I would think that for an _introduction_ you want the easy route...

Comment: If you just want to use tensor products, a watered down version of (3) is usually sufficient: $V\otimes W$ contains vectors that look like $v\otimes w$ and (obviously, since we want a vector space) linear combinations of these, and then $\otimes$ behaves like a product, as the notation suggests, so for example $u\otimes w+v\otimes w=(u+v)\otimes w$.

Comment: For f.d. vector spaces $V$, $W$ over a field $k$, $V \otimes_k W$ is naturally isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}_k(V^*, W)$, or, if you like a visibly symmetric construction, the space of $k$-valued $k$-bilinear forms on $V^* \times W^*$. This sounds baroque, but it accounts for most of how I directly use tensor products, and is perhaps more concrete than the usual construction. (It may also help students avoid the temptation to think that decomposable tensors fill out the tensor product.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/468043/what-is-the-best-way-to-introduce-tensor-products-to-undergrads#comment1215248_468043), how do you actually use such a definition? It seems you'd need to know at least that a tensor can be written reasonably uniquely as a sum of decomposables before doing anything with it (say, defining the value of a linear map), and then you're essentially at the full force of (3), or, if you choose to go that way, you've essentially given a (the usual?) rigorous definition (as a quotient of a free vector space on $V \times W$).

Comment: When I was learning linear algebra, I was just taught 3. I was only taught 2 when I learned module theory, which I think it is a more appropriate setting for it. (This might be less than ideal though if students were to take e.g. differential geometry before module theory.)

Comment: @LSpice: You are too much of a mathematician here, I think. It really works, as any physicist could confirm. (Two tensors are distinct unless they "obviously" represent the same vector.)

Comment: @LSpice: A quick random check: The way Nielsen, Chuang "define" tensor products in their book on quantum computing is very close to what I suggest.

Comment: @LSpice: From the point of view of physics, it's often enough to know how to manipulate objects without knowing very clearly what they might be. In fact, some older math books (by Weyl, for example) are written in the same charming style.

Comment: These sort of websites ask users to vote to close questions when they are **opinion-based**. Can you edit your question to make it not so blatantly one about opinions? It would help if you define in your question what you would consider "best" and what sort of "undergraduates" you are looking at. For example, for typical undergraduates in mathematics who do not wish to enter math research as a career, I am perfectly happy to sacrifice rigor; but you seem to regard this as a problem.